# How to extract max page number from html using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am having issues extracting the max/last page number at the bottom of the page. When I have tried the following code, I don't understand what I am doing wrong. My goal is to extract the only the number (currently 96), and if that isn't possible then at least extracting the href that contains the last page number in it (and I could just get the number from that).

```
#Example Page
page <- read_html("https://www.yachtworld.com/boats-for-sale/condition-used/type-sail/sort-price:asc/?currency=CAD&year=1990-2018&length=38-45&price=0-200000")


page %>% html_nodes(".nav-next") %>% html_attr("href") #my attempt to extract the number 96
page %>% html_nodes(".search-page-nav a") %>% html_attr("href") #my attempt to extract the href

{xml_nodeset (0)} #this is what is returned in both cases
```

SelectorGadget highlighting the desired node.

[image]

The chunk that I would like from inspect source.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination requires Javascript to run on the page in order to be present. This doesn't happen with rvest. Instead, one way is to calculate the number of pages based on text that is present, that has the number of results per page and the total result count.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

page <- read_html('https://www.yachtworld.com/boats-for-sale/condition-used/type-sail/sort-price:asc/?currency=CAD&year=1990-2018&length=38-45&price=0-200000&page=1')
result_text <- page %>% html_node('.page-selector-text') %>% html_text()
results_per_page <- result_text %>% stringr::str_match('- (\\d+)') %>% .[2] %>%  as.integer()
num_results <- result_text %>% stringr::str_match('of ([0-9,]+)') %>% .[2] %>% gsub(',','', .) %>%  as.integer()
num_pages <- ceiling(num_results/results_per_page)
print(num_pages)
```